# Powershell difference Add-ADGroupMember and Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory

What is in `powershell` the difference between `Add-ADGroupMember` and `Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership`?

According to this [Website](https://ss64.com/ps/add-adgroupmember.html):
You can only pass group objects to this cmdlet (`Add-ADGroupMember`) through the pipeline. To pass user objects through the pipeline, use `Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership`

Is there more to think of?

Comment: with `Add-ADGroupMember` you can add one or more members to one group. with `Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership` you can add one member to one or more groups.

Comment: @Olaf do you want to reply to it and you get my accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Thanks to [@Olaf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60735896/powershell-difference-add-adgroupmember-and-add-adprincipalgroupmembership#comment107458743_60735896), here is the answer:

**[`Add-ADGroupMember`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/add-adgroupmember?view=windowsserver2022-ps)**

you can add one or more members to one group

**[`Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/add-adprincipalgroupmembership?view=windowsserver2022-ps)**

you can add one member to one or more groups

Answer (score -2):

If anyone is looking for a command to copy a security groups member of properties instead of members themselves then here is the command:

Get-ADGroup -Identity "Old Group memberships to Clone" -Properties memberof -Verbose | select-object -Expandproperty memberof -Verbose | Add-ADGroupMember -Member "New Group that needs Old Group properties"

In this case we have nested groups for a file server based on specific access to folders for users in certain groups based on their occupation.

So if a certain security group is part of multiple other groups and needs to be cloned/copied then this command comes handy.

Didn't find any specifics for what I was looking for so this is the method I came up with.

Comment: This is not relacted to my question, therefore -1.